What additional steps are required to resolve the MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED error
I am using IBMCloud's code engine and the IBM Code engine sample project.
I am experiencing an authorization issue when connecting to a remote IBM MQ server from my Node.js application running in a Docker container. Despite configuring the necessary environment variables and settings, the application fails with the error:
MQError: OPEN: MQCC = MQCC_FAILED [2] MQRC = MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED [2035]

Environment and Setup:

Node.js Version: 18
Docker Base Image for Build Stage: ubuntu:20.04
Docker Base Image for Runtime Stage: node:16-slim
IBM MQ Node.js Module: ibmmq

# Stage 1: Build
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as builder

ENV NODE_VERSION 18
ENV APP_DIR /usr/local/clientapp

WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ make git ca-certificates \
    && curl --silent -k --location https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODE_VERSION}.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm

COPY . ${APP_DIR}

# Install packages for the application
RUN npm install --only=prod \
    && apt-get autoremove -y curl make gcc g++ python3 git \
    && apt-get purge -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && chmod a+rx ${APP_DIR}/*

# Stage 2: Runtime
FROM node:16-slim as clientAppImage

ENV APP_DIR /usr/local/clientapp
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

# Copy built application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder ${APP_DIR}/ ${APP_DIR}

# Copy the MQ configuration files
COPY ccdt/FOO_BAR.TAB ${APP_DIR}/mqconfig/FOO_BAR.TAB

# Set environment variables for MQ
ENV MQCHLLIB=${APP_DIR}/mqconfig
ENV MQCHLTAB=FOO_BAR.tab
ENV CCDTURL=file://${APP_DIR}/mqconfig/FOO_BAR.tab

EXPOSE 8080
CMD npm start


Code Snippet for MQ Connection
// approutes.js
const inboundQueueName = "SOME.INBOUND.QUEUE";
let mqclientInbound = new MQClient(inboundQueueName);


// mqclient.js
constructor(queueName) {
        this[_HCONNKEY] = null;
        this[_HOBJKEY] = null;
        this._queueName = queueName;
    }

performConnection() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.buildCNO()
            .then((cno) => {
                debug_info("CNO Built");
                return mq.ConnxPromise(MQDetails.QMGR, cno);
            })
            .then((hconn) => {
                debug_info("Connected to MQ");
                this[_HCONNKEY] = hconn;
                return this.performOpen();
            })
            .then((hObj) => {
                debug_info("MQ Queue is open");
                this[_HOBJKEY] = hObj;
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                debug_warn("Error establishing connection to MQ");
                debug_warn(err);
                reject(err);
            });
    });
    debug_info("Establishing Connection to MQ");
}

performOpen() {
    let od = new mq.MQOD();
    od.ObjectName = this._queueName;
    od.ObjectType = MQC.MQOT_Q;

    let openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE;
    debug_info("Performing open", this[_HCONNKEY]);

    return mq.OpenPromise(this[_HCONNKEY], od, openOptions); //<--- FAILING HERE
}


Debugging Attempts

File Presence: Verified the .tab file is present in the container.
File Case Sensitivity: Ensured consistent casing for file names.
Code Debugging: Added additional logging to verify where the error occurs.
Client vs. Server: Confirmed that the setup only uses client connections and does not require local queue manager connections.

Despite these steps, the application still encounters the authorization error.
Request for Help:

Authorization: What additional steps are required to resolve the MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED error when connecting to a remote IBM MQ server?
Configuration: Are there any specific configurations or settings that need to be adjusted either in the Dockerfile or the application code to properly authorize the connection?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Look at the errors generated to the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG,  this will show the cause.

Are you setting csp.UserId and csp.Password ? From your previous question it isn't clear if you need them or not.

The queue manager is remote and I don't have access to it. I only have access to MQ Client. Are there any MQ Client logs that would help? I'm not using UserId or Password because the remote MQIPT/MQ Manager admin told me that I don't need it. Should I request them anyway?

@Uhnj is the MQ admin able to check the queue manager log to help debug the 2035?

I just sent an email to request that they do. I'll provide an update when I hear back from them

If you are not setting userid / password then switch off the logic that does cno.SecurityParms = csp;

If you don't want to specify userid / password then you will need to switch off the following logic.
let csp = new mq.MQCSP();
csp.UserId = credentials.USER;
csp.Password = credentials.PASSWORD;
cno.SecurityParms = csp;


I figured out what the issue was. the options  let openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQC.MQOO_BROWSE; was causing an auth issue. As soon as I changed it to MQOO_OUTPUT I was able to connect just fine.
